# Uso de punteros y variables dinamicas para obtener un arreglo

Tags: c

Tengo las siguientes suposiciones acerca de que los punteros. Pueden ser interpretados como arreglos siempre y cuando sean inicializados para ocupar los espacios de memoria requeridos para "un arreglo". Quisiera entender un poco más acerca de como es que los punteros mejoran las dinámicas de un programa en C.

Aquí les dejo un programa que creo que muestra esta transformación de un puntero que apunta a un arreglo y como es que - un arreglo unidimensional es un apuntador constante, un arreglo bidimensional será un apuntador a apuntador constante (tipo **). ¿Como podría imprimir la matriz que hemos hecho, con un solo ciclo for y utilizando punteros?

```
/* matriz de n filas y cada fila de un número variable de elementos */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int **p;
  int n, m, i;
  do {
    printf("\n Numero de filas: "); scanf("%d", &n);
  }while(n <= 0);
  p = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    int j;
    printf("Número de elementos de fila %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &m);
    p[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
      printf("Valor del elemento p[%d][%d]: ", i+1, j+1);
      scanf("%d", &p[i][j]);
    }
  }
  // printf("%d", **p ); //Aqui va nuestra impresión de matriz
  return 0;
}
```

En cuanto tenga tiempo quizás pueda postear la respuesta. Gracias.

-----------------------------EDICIÓN------------------------------

Referente a las respuestas y comentarios que he recibido. Pongo un ejemplo donde ilustro un poco mas a fondo mi punto de vista. Y también, mostrar como se puede liberar la memoria, algo que dije al aire como un comentario, no una aseveración dentro de mi programa.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  float *pf = NULL;
  int num, i;
  do{
    printf("Número de elementos del vector: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
  }while(num < 1);
  /* Asigna memoria: num*tamaño bytes */
  pf = (float *) calloc(num, sizeof(float));
  if(pf == NULL)
  {
    puts("Error en la asignación de memoria.");
    return 1;
  }
  printf("Introduce %d valores \n", num);
  for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    printf("Valor del elemento %i: ", i);
    scanf("%f", &pf[i]);
  /* proceso del vector */
  }


  for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    printf("pf[%i]: %f\n", i+1, pf[i]); printf("\tTamaño de pf[%i]: %d\n", i+1, sizeof(pf[i]));}
  for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    printf("pf[%i]: %f\n", i+1,*pf); printf("\tTamaño de pf[%i]: %d\n", i+1, sizeof(*pf)); *pf++;}

/* liberación de la memoria ocupada */
  free(pf);

  for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    printf("pf[%i]: %f\n", i+1,*pf); printf("\tTamaño de pf[%i]: %d\n", i+1, sizeof(*pf)); *pf++;}
  for(i = 0; i < num; i++){
    printf("pf[%i]: %f\n", i+1, pf[i]); printf("\tTamaño de pf[%i]: %d\n", i+1, sizeof(pf[i]));}
  return 0;
}
```

EJECUCIÓN

```
N├║mero de elementos del vector: 2
Introduce 2 valores
Valor del elemento 0: 2
Valor del elemento 1: 2
pf[1]: 2.000000
        Tamaño de pf[1]: 4
pf[2]: 2.000000
        Tamaño de pf[2]: 4
pf[1]: 2.000000
        Tamaño de pf[1]: 4
pf[2]: 2.000000
        Tamaño de pf[2]: 4
pf[1]: 0.000000
        Tamaño de pf[1]: 4
pf[2]: 0.000000
        Tamaño de pf[2]: 4
pf[1]: 0.000000
        Tamaño de pf[1]: 4
pf[2]: 0.000000
        Tamaño de pf[2]: 4
```

Gracias por la valiosa retroalimentación. Sobre todo a [PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster). Ahora queda un poco mas claro.

Comment: Poder, puede hacerse, pero al final terminaríamos calculando los índices usando el módulo (resto de la división) de la variable contadora ya que las zonas de memoria alojadas en el primer nivel para los elementos de segundo nivel pueden no ser consecutivas ni estar alineadas en memoria. PD:  No estás liberando la memoria, `valgrind` se queja de ello.

Comment: PD: Mirando de nuevo el código, como el número de filas y el número de elementos en cada fila es variable, **no podemos** imprimir el contenido de `**p` sin almacenar esos datos en alguna estructura.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Los punteros] Pueden ser interpretados como arreglos siempre y cuando sean inicializados para ocupar los espacios de memoria requeridos para cada elemento.

Esto no es del todo falso, pero tampoco es cierto. El concepto que estás describiendo se conoce como...

#### Aritmética de Punteros.

El lenguaje C es de [tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte), lo que significa que todos los datos tienen un tipo específico que no puede cambiar *pero* si puede ser convertido. En el caso de los punteros, **siempre** serán puntero **a algo** además de tipo puntero.

Así que, un puntero a entero (`int *`) y un puntero a número de doble precisión (`double *`) son ambos punteros, pero son punteros **a algo** diferente y por tanto de tipo distinto. Este concepto es vital para la aritmética de punteros.

Se puede aplicar sobre un puntero operaciones aritméticas como la suma (`+`) y la resta (`-`)<sup>1</sup>, esto sumará al valor del puntero (que es la dirección de memoria en que se encuentra el dato apuntado) el tamaño del tipo apuntado, por ejemplo:

```
char *pc = NULL;
int *pi = NULL;

pc = pc + 1;
pi = pi + 1;
```

[En el código anterior](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L9HS5mQnARFpjFQA), `pc` y `pi` apuntan inicialmente a la dirección `0x0` (dirección nula) y al finalizar apuntan a la dirección `0x1` y `0x4` respectivamente pese a que ambos se les ha sumado el mismo valor; esto se debe a que `char` (tipo al que apunta `pc`) ocupa un byte de memoria mientras que `int` (tipo al que apunta `pi`) ocupa cuatro<sup>2</sup>.

El operador de indizado (los corchetes `[]`), es un [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico) de aritmética de punteros, la expresión `p[10]` siendo `p` un puntero, es equivalente a `*(p + 10)`<sup>3</sup> tal y como se indica en [el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (traducción mía):

> #### 6.5.2.1 Subindizado de Formaciones
>
> 2. Una expresión postfija seguida de una expresión entre corchetes `[]` es la designación subindizada de un elemento de un objeto formación. La definición del operador de subindizado `[]` es que `E1[E2]` es idéntico a `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Dadas las reglas de conversión que se aplican al operador binario `+`, si `E1` es un objeto formación (de manera equivalente, un puntero al elemento inicial de un objeto formación) y `E2` es un entero, `E1[E2]` designa el `E2`ésimo elemento de `E1` (contando desde cero).

Así pues, respondiendo a tu duda, los punteros pueden ser **siempre** interpretados como arreglos<sup>4</sup>, basta con aplicar aritmética sobre ellos, pero el [comportamiento será indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) si se trata como arreglo un puntero que no lo es tal y como dice [el estándar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (traducción mía):

> #### 6.5.6 Operadores Aditivos
>
> 8. […] Si tanto el puntero operado como el resultado apuntan a elementos del mismo objeto formación, o el siguiente tras el último elemento del objeto formación, la evaluación no producirá desbordamiento; en caso contrario el comportamiento es indefinido. […]

Un puntero que apunta a una variable, es conceptualmente una formación de un elemento, y dado que un puntero puede apuntar a varios datos a lo largo de su vida, puede ser usado indistintamente para apuntar a variables como para apuntar a formaciones por lo que indistintamente un puntero puede ser o no ser interpretado como un arreglo:

```
int v = 0;
int a[10] = {};
int *p = &v; // 'p' no es un arreglo
p = a; // Ahora 'p' es un arreglo!
```

---

> ¿Como podría imprimir la matriz que hemos hecho, con un solo ciclo for y utilizando punteros?

No puedes, por lo que veo en tu código no estás generando una matriz bidimensional si no una matriz *dientes de sierra*. Se conocen como matrices *dientes de sierra* aquellas en que cada fila de la matriz tiene un número variable de columnas.

Podrías imprimir la matriz con un solo ciclo `for` si la cantidad de columnas de cada fila fuese fijo:

```
for (int indice = 0, final = filas * columnas; indice != final; ++indice)
{
    int fila = indice / columnas;
    int columna = indice % columnas;

    printf("Valor del elemento p[%d][%d]: %d", fila, columna, p[fila][columna]);
}
```

---

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. Deja respirar a tu código. Apelotonar las líneas de código no hace que sea más molón, al contrario. Separa cada parte lógica del código para poder transmitir mejor las ideas a tu yo futuro y a la gente con la que trabajes.
2. Utiliza nombres de variables autoexplicativos. Nombres como `p`, `n`, `m`, `i` y `j` no aportan ninguna información de la misión de esas variables, de un vistazo no podemos saber qué significan ni por qué son necesarias.
3. El ámbito de las variables debe ser lo más pequeño posible. Es más fácil razonar sobre las variables si éstas están cerca del punto de uso.
4. Inicializa todas tus variables. Es menos propenso a errores.
5. Favorece el preincremento frente al postincremento. Lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para más detalles.

Siguiendo los consejos anteriores, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int **formacion = NULL;
  int filas = 0;

  do {
    printf("\n Numero de filas: "); scanf("%d", &filas);
  } while(filas <= 0);

  formacion = (int **) malloc(filas * sizeof(int *));
  for(int fila = 0; i < filas; ++fila)
  {
    int columnas = 0;
    printf("Número de elementos de fila %d: ", fila + 1);
    scanf("%d", &columnas);

    formacion[fila] = (int *)malloc(columnas * sizeof(int));

    for(int columna = 0; columna < columnas; ++columna)
    {
      printf("Valor del elemento formacion[%d][%d]: ", fila + 1, columna + 1);
      scanf("%d", &formacion[fila][columna]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

1. Consecuentemente también el `++`incremento, `--`decremento, `+=`autosuma y `-=`autoresta;
2. Estos valores pueden cambiar según [la arquitectura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitectura_de_computadoras).
3. Esto implica que `p[10]` y `10[p]` son equivalentes, por absurdo que parezca.
4. También conocidos como *formación* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: El problema sigue estando ahí... no se puede mostrar el contenido de `**p` porque en ningún sitio queda almacenado el número de filas ni el número de elementos por fila :( aún así, ¡buena explicación maestro! :D

Comment: @OscarGarcia se que el problema sigue estando ahí. Así lo he expresado justo antes de la sección "*Otras cosas a tener en cuenta*".

Comment: Aunque guardas `filas` no guardas las columnas por **cada** fila. Además, imagino que `scanf("%d", &m);` debería ser `scanf("%d", &columnas);`. Aún así mi +1 te lo llevaste ;)

Comment: @OscarGarcia efectivamente `scanf("%d", &m);` era incorrecto. Ya se que no guardo columnas por fila, así lo expreso en la sección previa a "*Otras cosas a tener en cuenta*" en que explícitamente expreso que **NO** se puede hacer lo que el usuario pide salvo que se conozcan los tamaños de la matriz.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que no hay otra manera de imprimir este resultado ademas de la forma canónica de varios ciclos for, que no usan un solo apuntador. El apuntador para hacer esto, requiere saber la posición de cada una de las direcciones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int **p;
  int n, m, i, j;
  do {
    printf("\n Numero de filas: "); scanf("%d", &n);
  }while(n <= 0);
  p = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    int j;
    printf("Número de elementos de fila %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &m);
    p[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
      printf("Valor del elemento p[%d][%d]: ", i+1, j+1);
      scanf("%d", &p[i][j]);
    }
  }
  // printf("%d", **p ); //Aqui va nuestra impresión de matriz
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
      printf("\nValor del elemento p[%d][%d]: %i\n", i+1, j+1, p[i][j]);

  return 0;
}
```

EJECUCIÓN

```
 Numero de filas: 2
N├║mero de elementos de fila 1: 2
Valor del elemento p[1][1]: 2
Valor del elemento p[1][2]: 2
N├║mero de elementos de fila 2: 2
Valor del elemento p[2][1]: 2
Valor del elemento p[2][2]: 2

Valor del elemento p[1][1]: 2

Valor del elemento p[1][2]: 2

Valor del elemento p[2][1]: 2

Valor del elemento p[2][2]: 2
```